# How Do I Save SQL Server Backup with Date Filename

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, back

Hi can I convert the following code so that the backup includes the date and time in the filename.

```
USE SysproCompany
GO
EXEC('BACKUP DATABASE [Company] TO  DISK = N''G:\SQLBackups\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company\MonthEndBackup.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, COPY_ONLY,INIT,
        NAME = N''MonthEndBackup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
        ')
PRINT 'Backup of Syspro Company started'
GO
PRINT 'Backup of Syspro Company complete'
```

Comment: You don't need `exec` to begin with. Just execute `BACKUP DATABASE` etc. You'll have to specify the file name yourself, paths don't use formatting characters or patterns. After all, different DBAs use completely different *folder* and naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need exec to begin with. Just execute

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Company] 
TO DISK = N''G:\SQLBackups\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company\MonthEndBackup.bak'' 
WITH NOFORMAT, COPY_ONLY,INIT,
     NAME = N''MonthEndBackup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

You'll have to specify the file name yourself, paths don't use formatting characters or patterns. After all, different DBAs use completely different folder and naming conventions. You can calculate the name in a variable before you use it.

A *far* better option though, the one used by most DBAs, is to use [Ola Hallengren's backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) to specify settings, folder and filename patterns, for multiple databases at a time.

The default pattern filename pattern is

```
'{ServerName}${InstanceName}_{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}_{Year}{Month}{Day}_{Hour}{Minute}{Second}_{FileNumber}.{FileExtension}',
```

A single command can be used to perform multiple operations, eg both backup all user databases *and* verify the backups, *and* clean up old backups :

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it lead me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXEC('BACKUP DATABASE [Company] TO  DISK = N''G:\SQLBackups\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company\MonthEndBackup' + CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, COPY_ONLY,INIT,
        NAME = N''MonthEndBackup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
        ')
```